# 'Snippet Serializer' object is not callable

Tags: django-rest-framework

Having just followed through the Part 5 of the official tutorial, I've run into a problem. The hyperlinked API works very well, expect when I click on a snippet. For instance, in the following:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "count": 1,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "http://localhost:8000/snippets/1/",
            "owner": "ankush",
            "title": "",
            "code": "print 123",
            "linenos": false,
            "language": "python",
            "style": "friendly",
            "highlight": "http://localhost:8000/snippets/1/highlight/"
        }
    ]
}
```

clicking on the url gives me this exception: **'Snippet Serializer' object is not callable**. I thought I had copied everything correctly from the tutorial, but apparently I hadn't. The code is here: https://github.com/ankush981/rest-demo

```
Finally, here's the entire trace:

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/snippets/1/

Django Version: 1.9.7
Python Version: 3.4.3
Installed Applications:
('rest_framework',
 'snippets',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  466.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  463.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get
  286.         return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py" in retrieve
  57.         serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)

File "/media/common/code/python/django-rest/tutorial/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py" in get_serializer
  111.         return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /snippets/1/
Exception Value: 'SnippetSerializer' object is not callable
```

Comment: Check imports in serializer.py and view.py

Comment: @HamedRostami Not sure what exactly to look for. I mean, everything else is working other than `/snippets/1/`. Could you please take a look at the source code? https://github.com/ankush981/rest-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok dear dotslash
i check that code :

Shouldn't this:

```python
class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    '''Retrieve, update or delete a snippet'''
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer()
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
```

Be that:

```python
class SnippetDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    '''Retrieve, update or delete a snippet'''
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
```

[image: Result]